# Formula for SMI Calculation for Sentinel-2

Tags: arcmap, sentinel-2, vegetation-index

The formula for Soil Moisture Index Calculation is written as; Soil Moisture Index= (NIR-SWIR)/(NIR+SWIR). So, what is the perfect formula for SMI calculation for Sentinel-2? SMI = (B8-B12) or (B8-B11) or any other???
I noticed some of the researchers calculate Radiance, Brightness Temperature etc. for SMI for Landsat-8. If that is necessary for Sentinel-2 too, then, what's the formula for this?

Comment: have you checked out this [website](https://www.indexdatabase.de/)?